# Adding multiple values to a SQL Query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, angularjs

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(ModelName data){
var query="Select * from Table where ColumnName ='"+data.ID+"'";

return Ok(Value);
}
```

In the above SQL query I want to add multiple ID's in data.ID. for an example I in one instance i need to get data for 2 ID's. in another time I need data from 20 ID's. Im using angular js to pass the json array with data. How can I do that. Do I have to write many data.Id1, data.id2 etc for all my Id data. Any help

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?? Select * from Table where ColumnName IN ('"+data.ID1+"','"+data.ID2'")

Comment: Nope. This is what I want to avoid. @ChrisF has understood my question. Check his answer a bit. Then you will understand my question. Sorry it it was a bit unclear due to the way I wrote the question

Comment: kk.. I might have missed reading the last line of your question.. Sorry about it.. Anyhow.. I think @ChrisF has a better answer for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are sanitising your inputs you can use:

```
var query = "Select * from Table where ColumnName in (" + list_of_ids + ")";
```

This will work whether you have one Id or several.

`list_of_ids` will have to be a comma delimited string of values:

> "a, b, c, d"

so you'll need some conversion method for adding each id to the list.

You could build up an list of values:

```
var myList = new List<string>();

if (data.Id1 is set)
{
    myList.Add(data.Id1.ToString());
}

etc.

string list_of_ids = string.Join(",", myList);
```

Comment: So if I pass a array of string directly using angular js in json this will this be possible?

Comment: The data I'm Passing from the angular form is a jason array with string values. Is there a way for me to directly store that json values to a list ?